# Query between 2 dates hours & minutes

Tags: mysql, hour, minute

I have a problem with a mysql query, and can't seem to find anything related.

I have a Date column in my table, called "date". The format is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

I am trying to count all data over several days, but only when the date is between 08:30:00 and 18:30:00.

I know how to use HOUR(date), but I don't know how to integrate the minutes in the query.

I've been thinking of using cases, but I'm not too sure about it.

Any help would be great.

Best regards,
Cheskq.

Edit with the query I've been doing:

```
select count(*), YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date)
from table
where YEAR(date) = 2014
AND HOUR(date) between 08 and 19
group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date);
```

Comment: Show us the SQL you've already tried

Comment: Done, sorry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest subtracting 30 minutes for the hour comparison:

```
select count(*), YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date)
from table
where YEAR(date) = 2014 AND
      HOUR(date - interval 30 minute) between 08 and 17
group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date);
```

Note that the upper limit is 17, assuming that the interval ends just before 18:30:00 (at, say, 18:29:59.999).

You can also express this as:

```
select count(*), YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date)
from table
where YEAR(date) = 2014 AND
      TIME(date) BETWEEN TIME('08:30:00') and TIME('18:30:00')
group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ya know, this is easier than it looks when you use the `TIME()` function.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(`date`)
  FROM table
 WHERE TIME(`date`) BETWEEN '08:30' AND '18:30'
 GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

If you want 8:30 up to but not including 18:30, use this instead. `BETWEEN` notoriously gives off-by-one errors when used for time ranges.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(`date`)
  FROM table
 WHERE TIME(`date`) >= '08:30'
   AND TIME(`date`) <  '18:30'
 GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y %h:%i') BETWEEN '2014 08:30' AND '2014 18:30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MINUTE(date)` as well:

```
WHERE (HOUR(date) = 8 AND MINUTE(date) >= 30) OR     # 08:30 - 09:00
      (HOUR(date) > 8 AND HOUR(date) < 18) OR        # 09:00 - 18:00
      (HOUR(date) = 18 AND MINUTE(date) <= 30)       # 18:00 - 18:30
```

Comment: Didn't think of doing this, thanks a lot, it works. :)